# Aptana Studio 3 does not start up due to "Syntax error: "(" unexpected Aptana"

Tags: aptana-studio

I followed the instructions provided [here](http://www.samclarke.com/2012/04/how-to-install-aptana-studio-3-on-ubuntu-12-04-lts-precise-pangolin/) to install Aptana Studio 3 in my Ubuntu 12.10. I have completed all the steps with out any problems. When I click the Aptana icon in my Unity bar nothing happens. No error pops up!

I gave permission on the sh file and on the directory (/opt/Aptana_Studio_3) but still same problem.

If I try executing the sh file in the /opt/Aptana_Studio_3 folder, it says "Syntax error: "(" unexpected Aptana". Also I cannot execute the Aptana binary file directly.

I have been trying to solve the problem for a while now. Any help would be much appreciated.

EDIT: I have Oracle Java 7 installed. I have read some post about backwards compatibility problem with Java 6 but dont know whether that's the issue. I will edit the question if I find something new.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue, but I solved it. I wasn't able to get Aptana Studio to open on Ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS (nor on Linux Mint 14).

I had followed the same instructions you did. I switched from OpenJDK 7 to Oracle Java 7 though still to no avail.

It turns out this was the issue. This is problem the problem you're expeirencing as well.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/13931352

> It appears that there is a mix up in the downloads. 32-bit and 64-bit got switched. If you are on 32-bit download 64-bit and vice versa. Hopefully it will be fixed soon.

Once I got the right download, it has worked splendidly. When downloading, click "Customize My Download."

Comment: Thanks for the response. For now I am using Aptana with Eclipse and it is working fine. Will select the right answer once tested.